# Batch File to strip numeric value from file name, create folder with said value, and move the file to the folder

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'll start off with noting that I'm completely new to batch processes.  I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out on my own (via the web) with no success. So now, to the experts.  What I need to do should be pretty simple for most.

I have 67,000+ files with the following naming convention `(acctnum_"A"_date_counter.filetype)`

> 1. 4312A201410011.TXT
> 2. 4321A201410012.DOC
> 3. 120232A201512311.PDF
> 4. 135392A201601011.TXT

I need to create folders based on the acctnum value, and then drop all files with that acctnum into the new folder.  Each file is delimited with an "A" to separate the acctnum from the date and counter.  The acctnum variable can be any number, and the length can be between 1 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use a `for /f` command that loops through your files.  Something like this might work for you:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=A." %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
    echo md %%a
    echo copy %%aA%%b.%%c %%a
)
```

This assumes that the only 'A' in each filename is the delimiter between the account number and the date counter.  If there is an 'A' in the file extension, this would have to be modified to account for that.  It also assumes that the only '.' (period) in the filename is the delimiter for the traditional file extension.

You can safely execute this with the commands `echo`'d.  Once the `echo`'d commands look like they'll do what you want them to do, remove the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Wes Larsons's solution improved to make it safe against:

- more than one `A` in the filename (*)
- `A`'s in the file extension
- multiple dots
- spaces in file names

(*): there is still a problem with two or more contiguous A's (`AA`) after `acctnum` (which probably isn't a problem for you): `for` will treat them as a single delimiter.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=A" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
    if not "%%c" == "" (
      ECHO md "%%b" 2>nul
      ECHO copy "%%bA%%c%%~xa" "%%b\"
    )
  )
)
```

(again, when the output seems ok, remove the `ECHO`'s)

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you very much!